# Expo-camera in React Native does not working correclty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to access camera using React native app. I have copied all the code from official documentation. Every one has done the same including the official expo-docs https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/camera/. My code to access the camera and take picture is

```
export default function Cameracontrol() {

        const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
        const [type, setType] = useState(Camera.Constants.Type.back);


        async function takePicture() {

            console.log(this.camera)
            if (this.camera) {
                console.log('Pictactue Taken')
                let photo = await this.camera.takePictureAsync();
            }
            else {
                console.log('Caera Not Open');

            }
        }


        useEffect(() => {
            (async () => {
                const { status } = await Camera.requestPermissionsAsync();
                setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
            })();
        }, []);

        if (hasPermission === null) {
            return <View />;
        }
        if (hasPermission === false) {
            return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
        }

        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <Camera style={{ flex: 1 }} type={type}
                ref={camera => this.camera = camera}
                >
                    <View
                        style={{
                            flex: 1,
                            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                            flexDirection: 'row',
                        }}>

                        <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "space-between", margin: 20 }}>

                            <TouchableOpacity

                                style={{
                                    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
                                    alignItems: 'center',
                                    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                                }}
                                onPress={() => {
                                    setType(
                                        type === Camera.Constants.Type.back
                                            ? Camera.Constants.Type.front
                                            : Camera.Constants.Type.back
                                    );
                                }}>
                                <Ionicons
                                    name="ios-photos"
                                    style={{ color: "#fff", fontSize: 40 }}
                                />

                            </TouchableOpacity>
                            <TouchableOpacity
                                onPress={takePicture}
                                style={{
                                    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
                                    alignItems: 'center',
                                    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                                }}>
                                <FontAwesome
                                    name="camera"
                                    style={{ color: "#fff", fontSize: 40 }}
                                />
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                            <TouchableOpacity
                                style={{
                                    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
                                    alignItems: 'center',
                                    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                                }}>
                                <MaterialCommunityIcons
                                    name="camera-switch"
                                    style={{ color: "#fff", fontSize: 40 }}
                                />
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </Camera>
            </View>
        );
    }
```

I am experiencing the following error.

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.camera = camera')
```

this error is strongly related with the line

```
ref={camera => this.camera = camera}
```

By removing this line of code the error is also removing.

I would really really appreciate if some boy would help me with this.

Comment: The docs have the code `ref={ref => { this.camera = ref}}`

Comment: Yeah I have used this as well.. Giving this error                                        
  "  undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.camera = _ref2') "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in a functional component, not a class. Therefore, you cannot use `this`. Also, `ref` is not working like in classes.

You should use `useRef` : https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

> `const inputEl=useRef(null);`
>
> `<input ref={inputEl} type="text" />`

Comment: Thank you so much it worked for me. I replaced my functional component with class component and it worked perfectly.